# Does "What is the sum of all the numbers $n$ if $n$ is a number greater than $7$ and less than $20$?" mean to include $7$ and $20$?

Tags: inequality, terminology

Should I count, for example, the numbers $7$ and $20$ when you say: "What is the sum of all the numbers $n$ if $n$ is a number greater than $7$ and less than $20$?"

And so would the set look like $[7,...,20]$ or $[8,...,19]?$

Comment: $7$ is not "greater than 7."

Comment: And this is the importance of using "strictly" or not in such problems.

Comment: For rigorous people, $8$ to $19$. For others, you don't know.

Comment: In fact "between 7 and 20" is much more ambiguous than "greater than 7 and less than 20".